# Integrate transit-java into an android studio project

Tags: java, android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

**What I have for now ?**

- I have a android studio project
- I don't have Maven and can't use it for now
- I got transit-java from github to a gerrit so now I have it locally using SourceTree

**What I want to do ?**

- Incorporate https://github.com/cognitect/transit-java/tree/v0.8.269 into my android studio project

**How can I do that ?**

- Knowing that transit-java seems to have other dependencies :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file add following lines at dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.cognitect:transit-java:0.8.269'
}
```

Make sure that repositories section contains Maven Central:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Or, in Android Studio you can add this dependency at File -> Project Structure -> Your app module -> Dependencies tab.

Comment: Awesome I don't know why I did not think of it earlier, you saved my day thanks =)